# node js pass context to callback

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js. I have this handlers.js file:

```
exports.Handlers = function(prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.db = new DBInstance();
};

exports.Handlers.prototype.getItemById = function(id) {
    var item = this.db.getItemById(id, function(error, item) {
        item.name = this.prefix + item.name;
        ...
        ...
    });
};
```

When I call:

```
var h = new Handlers();
h.getItemById(5);
```

I get an error since the context isn't the Handlers and this.prefix doesn't exists. I can fix it using this:

```
exports.Handlers.prototype.getItemById = function(id) {
    var scope = this;
    var item = this.db.getItemById(id, function(error, item) {
        item.name = scope.prefix + item.name;
        ...
        ...
    });
};
```

Is there any better way to pass the context to the callback?
What is the nodejs common way to pass the context to the callback?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Node implements ECMAScript 5, which has [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

I think that is what you are looking for.

```
exports.Handlers.prototype.getItemById = function(id) {
    var item = this.db.getItemById(id, (function(error, item) {
        item.name = this.prefix + item.name;
        ...
        ...
    }).bind(this)); //bind context to function
};
```

This works, however when using a closure as a callback, like you are doing, the most common way this is done is by storing the context in a variable that can be used in the closure.

This method is more common because many times callbacks can be deep and calling `bind` on each callback can be heavy; whereas defining `self` once is easy:

```
SomeObject.prototype.method = function(id, cb) {
    var self = this;
    this.getSomething(id, function(something) {
        //self is still in scope
        self.getSomethingElse(something.id, function(selse) {
            //self is still in scope and I didn't need to bind twice
            self.gotThemAll(selse.id, cb);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not related to Node.js, it's a general problem in JavaScript - and you already figured out the usual solution in JavaScript: Bind the `this` context to another variable (the one that you called `scope`), and use that within the callback to access the outer context.

Common names for this variable include `that` and `self`.

There *may* be a solution in ECMAScript 6 (codename "harmony") with the so-called *fat-arrow operator* that binds a function to an outer context. If you want to play with it today you might want to check out [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), a pre-compiler for JavaScript made by Microsoft which focuses on ES6-compatible syntax. Then your callback becomes something such as

```
foo(() => { console.log(this.bar); });
```

instead of:

```
var that = this;
foo(function () { console.log(that.bar); });
```

Just for the sake of completeness: jQuery's (and other frameworks) `bind` function generally works similar. See http://api.jquery.com/bind/ for an example.

HTH.

Comment: I know all that and I was looking simply the answer for node.js.. expected some $.proxy or _.bind for node. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

That is the common way. You will find your `scope` var named `self` or `_self`.

Later edit:

If you want to call a function within another context, this is the way:

```
getItemById.call(context, vars);
```

Comment: Isn't there any $.proxy or _.bind for node?

Comment: Edited the answer. You can call a function in a different context.

Comment: No, you wrong. I need a function that returns a function with the correct context. I can write the function myself, but I expect node.js will have such function.